# Match for today's date doesn't match correctly

Tags: perl, date

i'm writing a basic Perl script to check if there're files in certain directories their names contain today's date, the script works fine when there are files in the directory and returns TRUE, but doesn't return FALSE when no files withe the given criteria exist

the script is as below:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -w
use POSIX qw(strftime);
my $datestring = strftime "%Y%m%d", localtime;
opendir(DIR, 'C:\Perl');
@files = grep (/$datestring/,readdir(DIR));
closedir(DIR);
foreach $file (@files) {
    my $count = () = $file =~ /$datestring/;
    if ($count > 0) {
        print ("TRUE");
    }
    else 
    {
        print ("FALSE");
    }
}
```

the files names are like

```
export_opportunities_20181111-040005_20181124-040010.csv
export_opportunities_20181111-040005_20181122-040010.csv
```

Answer (score 1):

As commented by toolic, when you are already removing non-matching files here :

```
@files = grep (/$datestring/,readdir(DIR));
```

Hence your `for` loop will never see non-matching files.

Here are a few other comments on your code :

- always `use strict` and `use warnings` (there are several variables in your code snippet which are not properly declared)
- always check the return code of system calls such as `opendir`
- you can use the smartmatch operator in boolean context instead of assigning to the `$count` variable
- you don't need to use parentheses around argument to the built-in `print` function

Here is a cleaner version of your code :

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -w
use strict;
use warnings;
use POSIX qw(strftime);

my $datestring = strftime "%Y%m%d", localtime;
opendir(DIR, 'C:\Perl') or die "cannot open dir : $!";
my @files = readdir(DIR);
closedir(DIR);

foreach my $file (@files) {
    if ($file =~ /$datestring/) {
        print "TRUE\n";
    } else {
        print "FALSE\n";
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks fort the feedback, the output really matches for the result but it returns many trues along with each file name, i need only one true if there's one file match and one false if no file matches

Comment: @Kareem ok I edited the answer to produce the desired output

Answer (score 1):

You can use `@files` in scalar context to tell if `grep` returned any matches from `readdir`. In scalar context, `@files` is the number of elements in the array.

```
@files = grep (/$datestring/,readdir(DIR));
# this is more commonly written
#   @files = grep {/$datestring/} readdir(DIR);   

print @files > 0 ? "TRUE" : "FALSE";
# or
print scalar(@files)." files matched $datestring";
```

See also [List::Util](https://perldoc.perl.org/List/Util.html).

```
use v5.10;    
use List::Util qw<all any none>;
###
@files = readdir(DIR);
say 'all match' if all {/$datestring/} @files;
say 'at least one match' if any {/$datestring/} @files;
say 'no matches' if none {/$datestring/} @files;
```